# Yii CHtml::dropDownList. Same value under different labels

Tags: yii, html-select

```
CHtml::dropDownList('name','select',$listData,$htmlOptions);
```

Everything is OK until I faced one issue. I've got an array, which looks like this:

```
array(
    array('ua', 'Ukraine', '380'),
    array('ru', 'Russia', '7'),
...
    array('kz', 'Kazakhstan', '7'),
);
```

`$listData`  is an array of (value=>label). First I walked through array and made (code=>country) array as $listData. But I found that different countries may have the same code. I can use first "two letter geo" as key, and `$listData` will be an unique array. 
And what **if I need the same value but under different labels**?

---

It seems that the only Yii solution is to concatenate labels under one key(value).
Or use pure html and echo each option separate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sensible way to do this is with a new model, with a new id (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT), and hold the data in separate fields (country, geo, code.)

Create your listdata to be an array using only the new id and the country so the array looks something like this:

```
array( 0=>'Ukraine', 1=>'Russia', 2=>'Kazakhstan' );
```

This way you will only send the id, and figure out the data (geo, code, country) on the receiver side.

---

But I must ask about this:

> It seems that the only Yii solution is to concatenate labels under one key(value).

How do you want a option-tag to look like exactly?

```
<option value="ua" code="380">Ukraine</option>  // Like this?
```

Then you should set htmlOptions similar to this:

```
array(
    'ua'=>array('code'=>'380'),
    'ru'=>array('code'=>'7'),
    ...
);
```

Comment: `<option value="380">+380 (Ukraine)</option>` this is my option tag. And I want to have `<option value="7">+7 (Russia)</option><option value="7">+7 (Kazakhstan)</option>` And the thing is that this array is stored in a file, and I don't want to move it to database.

Comment: About html options - yes, this can be some kind of solution, but it needs some additional javascript, that will switch value and code before submit. I only want to send a numeric code from client to php to avoid unnecessary server-side loops. So it would be great if `$listData` could pass an array of `array('value'=>$value, 'label'=>$label)`...